# How to set id to a <tr> generated from a JSON response?

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

I want to set ID's dynamically to my rows. I have this:

```
function (json) {
        for (var ib = 0; ib < json.length; ib++) {
            var tableib = document.getElementById("treatments");
            var treatmentId = json[ib].id;
            var rowib = tableib.insertRow(-1);
            var cell1ib = rowib.insertCell(0);
            var cell2ib = rowib.insertCell(1);
            var cell3ib = rowib.insertCell(2);
            var cell4ib = rowib.insertCell(3);
            var cell5ib = rowib.insertCell(4);
            var buttonID = json[ib].id;
            cell1ib.innerHTML = json[ib].name;
            cell2ib.innerHTML = json[ib].time;
            cell3ib.innerHTML = json[ib].price + "kr";
            cell4ib.innerHTML = json[ib].details;
            cell5ib.innerHTML = "Button";
        }
    });
```

The ID I want to set is from a JSON response and has the variable **buttonID**. Is this even possible or should I append each row like this? :

```
$('#treatments').append("<tr><td>" + shopName + "</td><td>" + shopTime + "</td><td>" + shopPrice + "</td><td>" + shopDetails + "</td><td><center>" + editShop + deleteShop + "</center></td></tr>");
```

In which I could just alter my string that is beeing appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTMLTableRowElement` elements, like all `HTMLElement` elements, have an [`id` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-63534901), so:

```
rowib.id = buttonID;
```

...will do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the **DT_RowId** property in the data source object for the row. DataTables will automatically add the row ID.

To retrieve : 
$(row).parents('tr').attr(id')

Google:

Assign Row ID to Json Data - DataTables forums

Take help from this.

Comment: Not seeing any DataTables here. Just normal browser tables.

Comment: He is returning json, so this could bind with rows from datasource itself.

Comment: JSON is used all over the place without it having anything to do with DataTables. Nothing in the question suggests he's using them.

Comment: yeah.. but this may can cause confliction if not taken care. look  var buttonID = json[ib].id;
& same for  treatmentId. hope he will not use same id assignment for two different thing.

Comment: There is no conflict. The object he's calling `json` has nothing to do with the DOM. He's only assigning the `id` values he's retrieving from it one DOM element. Due respect, but the answer and subsequent comments are at most tangentially related to the question, and certainly don't answer it.